# Determine which strings contain the following characters in a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to write javascript code that allows me to extract which words (given as a list) contain either 1 or more characters in a given list of words.

```js
function filterWords(words, letters) {
    var myArrayOfLetters = Array.from(letters)

    var output;
    for(var i = 0; i<myArrayOfLetters.length; ++i)
    {
        output = words.filter(word => word.includes(myArrayOfLetters[i]))
    }

    return output;
}
```

This is the code I have so far but it is not working.

This is an example of the input and the output required:

```js
words = ['the','dog','got','a','bone']
letters = 'ae'

output = ['the','a','bone']
```

As you can see the output contains all the words that have either 'a' or 'e' in them or both.

How would I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, but you have your loops backward. You want to use the `filter` as the *outer* loop, and the loop over the array of letters as the *inner* loop, since you want to know if a word has any of those letters in it. The inner loop can be a call to the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method rather than an explicit loop:

```
function filterWords(words, letters) {
    const myArrayOfLetters = Array.from(letters);
    const output = words.filter((word) =>
         myArrayOfLetters.some((letter) => word.includes(letter))
    );
    return output;
}
```

`some` returns `true` if the callback ever returns `true` (or any truthy value), or `false` if the callback never does.

Live Example:

```js
function filterWords(words, letters) {
    const myArrayOfLetters = Array.from(letters);
    const output = words.filter((word) => myArrayOfLetters.some((letter) => word.includes(letter)));
    return output;
}
const words = ["the", "dog", "got", "a", "bone"];
const letters = "ae";
console.log(filterWords(words, letters));
```

Here's an example with a word that has both `a` *and* `e` in it; note it's only included once:

```js
function filterWords(words, letters) {
    const myArrayOfLetters = Array.from(letters);
    const output = words.filter((word) => myArrayOfLetters.some((letter) => word.includes(letter)));
    return output;
}
const words = ["the", "dog", "got", "a", "really", "nice", "bone"];
const letters = "ae";
console.log(filterWords(words, letters));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it with the help of [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let words = ['the', 'dog', 'got', 'a', 'bone'];
const letters = 'ae';

const splittedLetters = letters.split('');

const res = words.filter(item => {
    return splittedLetters.some(word => item.includes(word));
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let words = ['javascript', 'java', 'ruby', 'python', 'php'];
let filterWords =(words, chars) => {
      return words.filter(word => word.split('').some(char => chars.includes(char)));
}
console.log(filterWords(words, 'pa')); //['JavaScript', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Unexplained code is not a useful answer to a question.